# Using node_save to update an existing node saves cached data

Tags: 6, nodes

I am using Conditional Actions in Ubercart on Drupal 6 to create a node when a certain product class is purchased.

Everything is firing correctly. I have check and double-checked the code to see what might be wrong and I can't see it. I'm hoping you might know something that will help.

Here is the code:

```
$spons_node = node_load($sponsorship['sponsorship_nid']);
$spons_node->field_body[0]['value'] = "Online recurring payment added (".date("m-d-Y H:ia", time()).")\n".$spons_node->field_body[0]['value'];
$spons_node->field_sponsor_amount[0]['value'] = number_format($product->price,2);
$spons_node->field_sponsor[0]['uid'] = $order->uid;
$spons_node->field_payment_type[0]['value'] = $order->payment_method;
$spons_node->field_recurrance_type[0]['value'] = str_replace("every","",strtolower(str_replace(" ","",$product->data['attributes']['Donation Frequency'][0])));
$spons_node->field_initial_order_id[0]['value'] = $order->order_id;
$spons_node->field_recurring_item_id[0]['value'] = (int) $new_query['pfid'];
node_save($spons_node);
$message = "Sponsorship for <em>".$product->title."</em> has been updated.";
uc_order_comment_save($order->order_id, '0', $message, $type='admin', $status = 1, $notify = FALSE);
unset($spons_node);
unset($new_query);
$spons_updated = TRUE;
```

I used `drupal_set_message("<pre>".print_r($spons_node,TRUE)."</pre>");`, inserted just before the `node_save` command, to ensure the node was being built properly. All of the fields were updated correctly.

But something is going on with `node_save`. My Drupal installation is telling me that the node in question was updated, but none of the changed data is being stored. It looks like it's defaulting to the cached data.

I've also tried using `node_load($sponsorship['sponsorship_nid'],NULL, TRUE);` to force a cache reload, but that's not working.

Ideas welcome.

Comment: try `node_load(FALSE, NULL, TRUE);` after saving the node to clear the cache and see what happens when you load it again...

Comment: You. Are. My. Hero. Totally worked! Thank you so much.